# android is here we use expandlistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I know this question is wrong but would you answer me please ?

I have an app that allow user to enter many addresses. I want to show him all of his addresses so I choose `ExpandedListView` to handle the label of each address and when the user click on any `label`, he can see the city and street of that address. I want to ask that is use of `ExpandListView` is right here? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any reason why using `ExpandableListView` would be wrong in this case.

Yes, you can use it. This is how I imagine this:

[image]

Where `Address 2` is currently expanded.

Answer (score 1):

Definatly you can use exapandable list view.

prefer Url :

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html

[image: Like that]